What is the output of "date -u +%V$(uname)|sha224sum|sed 's/\W//g'"
I am trying  to register on the arch linux forum and am asked for the output of this command:
date -u +%V$(uname)|sha224sum|sed 's/\W//g'

Why am I being asked this and is it safe to run? I am unable to type one of the characters.

The command is safe to run.
It's a pipeline of three separate commands:

date -u +%V$(uname). This outputs the ISO 8601 week number of the current week, and then concatenates that with the output of the uname command.  On a Linux system, the uname command would output the string Linux.  If you ran this command separately this week, it would output 42Linux (assuming the default value of the shell variable IFS, or else it may affect the expansion of the unquoted command substitution in ways that I doubt the people that put this little "test" together thought about).

sha224sum.  This takes the previous command's output and calculates a SHA224 hash of the data.  If the input is 42Linux (followed by a newline), this command would output 51cca30ebd0f07d0f4fc71e5a9aeff1b87ec6364baf2fcf98ec8ae3f  -.

Since the sha224sum command outputs a few whitespace characters and a dash at the end, the sed command is used to "clean it up" by removing all "non-word characters".  This would more portably be written tr -dc '[:alnum:]_\n', or, since we only want to keep hexadecimal digits, tr -dc '[:xdigit:]\n'.


The final output would thus be
51cca30ebd0f07d0f4fc71e5a9aeff1b87ec6364baf2fcf98ec8ae3f

... given that the pipeline was executed on a Linux machine this week.
On a macOS system, this would (this week) instead output
341838f3607dd25072f7bfffb3d9c528161b2c707449ddd4be59245d

... because uname would give us Darwin rather than Linux.
I suppose this is a way for the forum you're registering for to vet out any prospecting members who aren't actually running Linux systems, which seems a bit silly if you ask me.

agreed on the silliness, but it would have weeded out tom if they weren't curageous enough to ask. I guess it's also something that a forum bot swarm operator would be hesitant to implement themselves, because if they did, and someone started targeting bot swarm operators, they'd possible just include rm -rf $home in there or such once they detect a bot is trying to pass that "humanity-test".
